# How can I add a class to an input of type submit in html such as it won't be removed once added?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to add a class to an input of type submit  I tried using javascript input is inside a form

```
<input type='submit' name='$emri" . "$mbiemri" . "submit" . "$depart'" . " value='Vlereso' onclick='disable(this)'>
```

where disable is a function :

```
 function disable(element)
          {
            element.classList.add('disabled');
          }
```

when the input is clicked it adds the class but when the action is sent the class is removed again  , what I want to do is  when I click the input I don't want it to be clickable anymore so I am trying to add class disabled and I don't want it to be removed , is it possible to do it with JS or PHP is needed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store a boolean inside `sessionStorage` and when the page loads check if the boolean is true and if so disable the button.

sessionStorage will delete itself once the window gets closed.

Example:

pagescript.js:

```
let shouldDisableInput = sessionStorage.getItem('shouldDisableInput')
if(shouldDisableInput !== undefined){
    $('#input-id').classList.add('disabled') //or $('#input-id').prop('disabled', true);
}
function disable(element){
    element.classList.add('disabled');
    sessionStorage.setItem('shouldDisableInput', 'true')
}
```

page.html:

```
<input id="input-id" type='submit' name='$emri" . "$mbiemri" . "submit" . "$depart'" . " value='Vlereso' onclick='disable(this)'>
```

don't forget to add the `pagescript.js` inside the body of the html.

More info on sessionStorage:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Comment: since I've got a bunch of  inputs which actually do the same function but for different persons  and actually it is account based if one user clicks it the other should be still able to click it if hasn't done such yet , I think the bool you talking about I should store it in a database for each input and then for each user it will be checked if it's clicked or not

Comment: Are you talking about logging in? Is the input specific to logging in? You should not store bools related to Front-End inputs inside your database.

Comment: sessionStorage is user specific, and is saved on the client's computer. So if someone logs in for example and you store something inside their sessionStorage other users will not have that information available for them, that's why we say sessionStorage is client-side.

Answer (score 2):

When you click on the submit button, it will submit the form data (if present) to the target url, which is the current url by default. What you see is that the page is being reloaded afresh, so the class that you added will not be there anymore, because technically, it's a new page.

What you need to do is to disable the button right at the page load, if it's not to be used again. (Arguably you could remove the button altogether, because it's no use to have a disabled button that is never to be used again.)

To disable the `<input ...`, just add the attribute `disabled` to the tag.

Comment: actually I don't want to remove entirely because I am planning to make later on something that will make the button automatically be available again  , but how can I disable the button after the page loads ?

Comment: You need a way to tell if the page is freshly loaded or via the submit button. The easiest way to know that it's the latter case is by a parameter (you can use a `<input type="hidden" ...` which then will appear in the query string.

Comment: Alternatively, if you can, use AJAX to submit the form so you _don't_ reload the page.

Comment: @Andy I am not familiar with AJAX but seems that I need to learn it

Answer (score 0):

You can send a hidden variable with some value from php page, and check in html page if the variable is exists then print disable tag.

Comment: Imma try it , I think that will do it

Comment: I hope you could find a way

Comment: the problem now is that I have a bunch of inputs so when one is clicked it has to be disabled I am afraid this will take more than I thought